# In SQL, how to multiply data of two columns for third column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I want to multiply the data of two columns and show it in the third column.

For example:

```
1st Column: Quantity
2nd Column: Rate
3rd Column: Price
```

I want to multiply as user enters the data for quantity and rate like `Quantity=2`, `rate=50` automatically in price column I want 100 to be mentioned.

Using C#, VS2010, SQL 2008

**Edit:** I want to show the data at the `DataGridView` what are the possible solutions, I used `DataAdapter` and `DataSet` to update the database:

```
this.table2TableAdapter.Update(testingDataSet);
```

Comment: Please don't ask this question again. Edit this question to add more details that may be helpful.

Comment: lol u made edit but didnt reply (funny isnt).

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT QUANTITY, RATE, QUANTITY*RATE as PRICE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: and i have to paste it in Price formula ??

Comment: What do mean by *Price formula* ?

Comment: i mean where to add this formula i tried many ways but unable to execute this query and i am using Data grid view

Comment: @user485190: This is how you can calculate the Price values in SQL. If you want to know what to do about the result set in the client application, then it would most probably be a different question (and should be posted as a new one accordingly).